# Compiler flagging error for using array size variable

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation

This simple piece of code for some reason is causing the compiler to show an error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
size_t c_string_length{15}; 
auto* selection{new char[c_string_length]{"Biggie Smalls"}};
for(size_t i{};i<c_string_length;i++)
    cout<<selection[i];
    
delete [] selection;

return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is this:

```
    error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds 
    14 | char* selection{new char[c_string_length]{"Biggie Smalls"}};
       |                                                          ^
```

But as soon as I replace the size (given by the variable
**c_string_length**
) of the dynamically allocated array  with an integer - say 15, the program runs just fine and displays the intended output.
Why is that? It doesn't have to do with the datatype of the array size variable used, I checked using **int**.

Comment: Works well in clang and gcc. Getting `fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.` in msvc. What compiler are you using?

Comment: It is an online compiler. This one: 
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason behind the error. It is because, to the compiler, it is a bit confusing - the size of the array, which is supposed to be constant size. When simply using the variable **c_string_length**, we are implying that the size is not fixed and subject to change.
The fix is to tell the compiler that **c_string_length** is a constant; by way of:

```
const size_t c_string_length{15};
```

That's all, now the compiler is sure that **c_string_length** is a constant and can use it without any confusion.

Comment: Actually in this case, array size not necessarily needs to be constant as you allocate it dynamically. Looks like the problem in something else.